# nested let blocks in kotlin and valiadation

Tags: kotlin, scope, functional-programming, let

I want to handle validation in functional approach. I have user validation logic as below

1. if user object is null throw an exception
2. if the user is not active throw an exception
3. if the user type is super do nothing. If user type is admin do some operation.

In my code snippet I am throwing an exception if generated random number is even, otherwise complete the flow.

```
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

import java.time.Instant
import java.util.UUID
import java.lang.IllegalStateException
import java.util.Random
fun main() {
    val user : User? = User(UUID.randomUUID(),Instant.now(),UserStatus.ACTIVE,UserType.SUPER) 
     //val user : User? =  User(UUID.randomUUID(),Instant.now(),UserStatus.ACTIVE,UserType.NORMAL) // works fine

    user?.let{ existing -> existing.takeIf{it.status == UserStatus.ACTIVE}?.let{ activeUser ->
            activeUser.takeUnless{ user -> user.userType == UserType.SUPER}?.let{
                    val number =  Random().nextInt(5);
                    println(number)
                    if(number %2 == 0) throw IllegalStateException("invalid random number")
            }
    }?: throw IllegalStateException("User is not active right now")

    } ?:throw IllegalStateException("user not created at all")
}

data class User(val uuid:UUID, val created:Instant, val status:UserStatus, val userType:UserType)



enum class UserStatus {
    ACTIVE,INACTIVE
}

enum class UserType{
    SUPER,NORMAL
}
```

when generated random number is odd its throwing an error message `user is not active right now` which is not correct. it should silently complete the function call.Any one help me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Nothing in the code says "user is not active". Did you mean "subscription"?

Comment: yes.. updated the code to reflect the correct one.

Comment: Can you put the code in the question please and not a 3rd party site?

Comment: done..updated the code

Comment: Please use proper indentation so that we can follow the code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner block

```
existing.takeIf { it.status == UserStatus.ACTIVE }?.let { activeUser ->
    activeUser.takeUnless { user -> user.userType == UserType.SUPER }?.let {
        val number = Random().nextInt(5);
        println(number)
        if (number % 2 == 0) throw IllegalStateException("invalid random number")
    }
} ?: throw IllegalStateException("User is not active right now")
```

You have a not null value.

Since you're not chaining the `?.` calls. The better idea is to do early return/throw.

```
val existing = user ?: throw IllegalStateException("user not created at all")
```

So the nested block can be flattened.

The second exception "User is not active right now" happens when one of the two checks is not met.
The programming concept to describe this kind of business logic is not nullable variables. A regular old `if` check is much cleaner.

```
if (existing.status != UserStatus.ACTIVE || existing.userType == UserType.SUPER) {
    throw IllegalStateException("User is not active right now")
}
```

BTW your error message seems wrong.

---

By "functional approach", I think you mean having the code expression-based. But nullable type is not powerful enough for your use case.
You should be looking for `Either` or `Try`. Both of them are available in the [Arrow library](https://arrow-kt.io/). They are both monads. Their chaining (`flatMap`), like the `?.let` calls, also require the callback hell.

In some languages, there is syntactic sugar to flatten the callback hell of `flatMap`s. You can take a look at the [Monad Comprehensions](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monad_comprehensions/), and see if you like that.

If not, no problem. In Kotlin, there is no shame associated with early return/throw.

Be pragmatic.